# Set-Acl change domain for user Account powershell

Tags: powershell, directory, dns

Hello I would like to know how I can change the domain of a folder > security parameter > property > MYDOMAIN\Adm_User I want to change only MYDOMAIN in Powershell thank you very much for your help

```
t$ACL = Get-ACL .\smithb
$Group = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Builtin", "Administrators")
$ACL.SetOwner($Group)
Set-Acl -Path .\smithb\profile.v2 -AclObject $ACL
```

````
```
t$ACL = Get-ACL C:\Gabriel
$Group = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("Builtin", "Administrators")
$ACL.SetOwner($Group)
Set-Acl -Path C:\Gabriel -AclObject $ACL
```
````

Comment: What is `t$ACL`?

Comment: Please look at this URL: Change File and Folder Ownership https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/04/18/how-to-manage-file-system-acls-with-powershell-scripts/#Change_File_and_Folder_Ownership

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Give Ownership using PowerShell
$ACL = Get-Acl -Path "C:\Gabriel"
$User = New-Object System.Security.Principal.Ntaccount("Builtin", "Administrators")
$ACL.SetOwner($User)
$ACL | Set-Acl -Path "C:\Gabriel"
Get-ACL -Path "C:\Gabriel"
```